# Creating a char** of words read in from getline() in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I'm trying to create a dynamic char** of words as they are read in from getline()

```
while ((lineLength = getline(&line, &n, stdin)) != -1) {
    if(lineLength > 0)
    {
        if(line[lineLength - 1] == '\n')
        {
            line[lineLength - 1] = '\0';
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm having issues using malloc() to create the element and dynamically allocate the memory for it. I'm currently trying to

```
char** words = (char**)malloc(x*sizeof(char));
```

but am getting errors. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: If it's dynamic you can't initialize this in advance, you allocate as you receive more data.

Comment: I think you need to post a bit more of your actual code as it's difficult to formulate a definitive answer with the amount you've posted. But, I do believe that what you really want is: `char** words = malloc(x * sizeof(char *));` And, then, you'll want to loop on (e.g.) `for (i = 0; i < x;  ++x) words[i] = strdup(...);`. This isn't the full solution, but may be a bit closer

Comment: I think asking for "Creating a char** " indicates that you are on the wrong track. It is not the double pointer you need to create, it is the complex data structure behind that.

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is 1.  `sizeof (char*)` is almost never 1.  HTH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(char)` is different than `sizeof(char*)`. `sizeof(char)` is generally 1, while the size of a pointer is implementation-defined, but always larger than that. You really aren't allocating enough room for your pointer. Because you have a pointer of pointers, I think the code you really want is

```
char** words = (char**)malloc(x*sizeof(char*));
```